# No microphone working on Windows 10 and Intel mainboard

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard, microphone

I'm using Windows 10 64 Bit with an Intel DH55HC mainboard.

I am using the onboard audio device but unfortunately I can't get my headset to work.

Whenever I try to configure my microphone, Windows tells me to check that my audio device is properly configured.

No port is working, and another headset isn't working as well. How can I get my microphone to function properly?

Comment: Have you installed drivers that specifically indicate they are compatible with Windows 10?  Are you able to confirm this port worked at some point?  Are you able to confirm this port worked with Windows 10 installed at some point?  The behavior you describe can either indicate a driver problem or a hardware problem.  Have you confirmed that microphone actually works? Please update your question to include all of this vital information in the body of your question.  It does not appear the Realtek device on this motherboard supports Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound Since there are no Windows 10 audio drivers on the Intel website it may well be that Windows 10 is not fully supported.

Comment: Only you know if you always had this problem or it just surfaced recently

Comment: @Ramhound I've always had this problem.